# How to replace a column after a search in Ag-Grid?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const columns = [ 
{ headerName: "Product", field: "product"}, 
{ headerName: "Name", field: "name" }, 
{ headerName: "Date", field: "date" },
];
```

```
const columns1 = [ 
{ headerName: "Type", field: "type" }, 
{ headerName: "Open", field: "open" }, 
{ headerName: "High", field: "high" }, 
{ headerName: "Percentage", field: "pct" }
];
```

```
useEffect(() => { 
  fetch(`http://localhost:8080/all?product=${search}`) 
    .then(res => { return res.json();
    })
    .then (data => { setRowData(data);
    })
}, [search]); 

return ( 
  <div className="Products">   
    <SearchBar onSubmit={setSearch} />
    <div 
       className="ag-theme-balham" 
       style={{ 
          height: "300px", 
        width: "600px" 
         }} 
    > 
        <AgGridReact
          columnDefs={columns} 
        rowData={rowData}
        /> 
    </div> 
  </div> 
)
function SearchBar(props) { 
    const [innerSearch, setInnerSearch] = useState(""); 
    return ( 
      <div > 
        <input 
          aria-labelledby="search-button" 
          name="search" 
          id="search" 
          type="search" 
          value={innerSearch} 
          onChange={e => setInnerSearch(e.target.value)} 
        />  
  
        <button 
          id="search-button" 
          type="button" 
          onClick={() => props.onSubmit(innerSearch)} 
        > 
          Search 
        </button> 
      </div> 
    ); 
  } 
};
```

I've gone through a lot of resources to try and get my **columns1** to appear after a search, rather than **columns**. All of the headers from both columns are fields in my API and they all display properly, but I can't seem to split them up and only have **columns1** appear when a search is made.

No matter what I try and put in my search bar function, or if I create two `<AgGrid/>` tables and try to have only one appear, it doesn't work. Either all my columns appear together, or two tables appear.